# Search form in Django

Tags: django

I want to query my database for multiple conditions, like for instance I want to have a specific post from the foo author with the most comments. This query would be quite easy and straightforward, but I want that the user specifies the conditions. That means that I currently have a form like that one on my website:

[image]

Since the user is not pressured to set every condition there can be fields empty to search for. ( he doesn't select a hero for example ). I could now make an if statement for each condition to check if the user actually submitted one or not ( `if request.POST.get('author')` ) but that would be too much code I guess...

How did you guys approach such search forms in django? Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter a [Django queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/). Querysets are chainable, so you can apply successive filters based on the conditions specified by the user. Having `if` statements for four conditions doesn't seem too excessive:

```
def search_view(request):
    results = Guide.objects.all()

    title = request.POST.get('title')
    if title:
        results = results.filter(title__icontains=title)

    # other conditions...

    hero = request.POST.get('hero', 'all')
    if hero != 'all':
        results = results.filter(hero=hero)

    render_to_response('search_results.html', {'results': results})
```

Comment: That sounds very awesome! I will implement that asap :D Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MODEL_NAME.objects.filter()`, and provide defaults.

And then, you can use `__` to either go another level into relationships, or to run custom queries such as less than, greater than etc. (more info here: [Django Querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/))

For example:

```
def get_hero(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        hero_name = request.GET.get('hero_name', 'DEFAULT_HERO')
        guide_title = request.GET.get('guide_title', 'DEFAULT_TITLE')

        heros = Hero.objects.filter(hero__name=hero_name, guide__title=guide_title) 

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'heros': heros})
```